# How do I stop docker's virtual machine so I can install VirtualBox?

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I am on a Mac. I installed docker and ran the terminal. It starts the virtual machine. Now I want to install VirtualBox but the installation program complains that there is a virtual machine running that I must stop first. I exited the terminal and it said things about saving stuff but the VirtualBox installation program still says I need to stop a virtual machine. How do I do that? Since I don't have Virtualbox installed yet I don't know how to access it...

Comment: docker is service  you cant close it with just closing terminal

Answer (score 17, accepted):

And now I feel silly, but the command is:

```
docker-machine stop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these commands, to start or stop your default docker machine

To start docker - `docker-machine start`

To stop docker - `docker-machine stop`